# Overflow working in Mozilla but not on Chrome and Android (-webkit-) browser

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, google-chrome, hybrid-mobile-app

I want a scroll-bar in my page so I can scroll down for content. Header/Footer is fixed.

**Issue :** In Chrome it doesn't show a scroll-bar, and also the image is overlapping with the header. 
In Mozilla it shows correctly. Check screenshots.

[image: You can check the outputs from both browsers here.]

Here is my HTML.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="popup" class="popupimages hidden" id="imagesPopup">
  <header class="" id="customheader">
    <a style="visibility: visible;" class="backButton button">Done</a>
    <h1 id="pageTitle"></h1>
  </header>

  <div class="dump" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <img src="http://www.freeallimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/cat-clipart-1.gif" class="popimg">
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="info">
    <h1>we will append product info here.. <br>
                        will allow scroll.<br>
                        End of Info section.</h1>
  </div>

  <footer class="" id="customfooter" >
     <h2 id="curr_price" style="float: left; width: 30%;"></h2>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS.

```
.popimg{
    /*border:"1px solid",*/
    width:"320px",
    height:"320px",
    marginLeft:"-160px",
    marginTop: "-160px",
    backgroundColor:"#aaa"             
} 

.popupimages img{
    position:relative;
    width:200px; /*image width */
    height:200px; /*image height */
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-50px; /*image width/2 */
    margin-top:-40px; /*image height/2 */
    /*border: 1px solid #bbb;*/
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:2px; 
} 

.popupimages {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    left:50%; 
    top:50%;
    bottom: 20%; 
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. check this : http://jsfiddle.net/7kzoLcs5/

Comment: I've already checked in jsfiddle. The scroll bar there depends on the size of fiddle output box w.r.t the browser. Try removing the `overflow-y: auto;` from CSS, still that scroll will be there because that is jsfiddle property. However my question totally depends on running in a browser(no fiddle-ing) view and believe me the outputs are genuinely what I've posted above.